# AIR Stagewebview not displaying youtube videos

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have trying to load youtube videos using stagewebview on AIR Desktop. (windows 10)
Code below:

```
var SWV:StageWebView = new StageWebView(true);
SWV.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, swvErrorHandler);
var swvHeight:Number = stage.stageHeight - (75);
var swvWidth:Number = stage.stageWidth;
var swvYCoord:Number = 75;
SWV.stage = stage;
SWV.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, swvYCoord, swvWidth, swvHeight);
var vId:String = 'QowwaefoCec';
var urlToLoad:String = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+vId+"?rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=0";
SWV.loadURL(urlToLoad);
```

Running the code gives a window with black background. Right clicking on it pops up the adobe flashplayer menu stating "Movie not loaded". Flash version is 25.0.0.148

If i use 
    urlToLoad="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+vId;
i get a malformed youtube page with majority of elements missing.

Tried with number of videos. result is always the same.

Can any one help please? I remember having tried out the above code a year or so back (when i was testing something else). It had definitely worked then. Cant fathom why it doesnot work now. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your **code works fine** within Flash CS debugger and as EXE app. I've tested it (minus `SWV.addEventListener...` and also that `StageWebView(true)` does not need the `true` part). All I can suggest is (1) Wait a little while (60 secs) just to see if black screen becomes video poster... (2) Make a basic test (white bg) using your shown code only. If any part of white canvas changes t black at least it's signal of trying to load the YT video.  Finally _""Movie not loaded"_ happens because some SWF could not be loaded, is there such a thing going on in your not-shown part of code?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
var urlToLoad:String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body><iframe style=\"border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; padding:0px; margin:0px\" id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + vId + "?fs=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></body></html>";
SWV.loadString(urlToLoad, "text/html" );
```

Comment: Tried using your suggested url. Same result. Black window. except the right click menu has now options like zoom in, zoom out etc.

Comment: The problem is that you are using a `StageWebView`. Do you have to use ot ?

Comment: What are the options other than stagewebview? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Before that, check my latest answer - try that it should work.

Comment: actionscript error...Error #2044: Unhandled ErrorEvent:. text=The protocol is not supported.

Comment: You need to use `SWV.loadString` - see updated answer

Comment: I am not using Starling. The error i mentioned earlier was a run time error.

Comment: OK, remove that line, just stick to using `SWV.loadString`

Comment: Any progress? Did that help?

Comment: no. SWV.load string gives argument error.  ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on flash.media::StageWebView/loadURL(). Expected 1, got 2.

Comment: You need to use `loadString`

Comment: No Luck even with loadString. (Sorry to have missed the loadString earlier). Still getting the black window. Infact the black window is of a much smaller height.

Comment: That's not possible, I tested it myself. Are you actually **exporting and testing this?** - Because while previewing it in adobe content preview will never work, you need to export it and see what happens **in the HTML**.

Comment: I am running it in flashdevelop--debug mode. By export do you mean creating an exe and running it?

Comment: let me try and get back

Comment: No Luck even with exe. Since it is working at your end and not mine, wonder what is it here that is not allowing the video to run. Could you suggest alternatives to stagewebview?

Comment: Look at this post: http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2008/10/14/youtube-in-air/

Comment: Thank you for the input. Will try out the HTMLLoader. But i wonder if it will work.

Comment: Continutation of prev msg.  HTMLLoader docu states "On desktop computers (in the desktop and extended desktop profiles), the HTMLLoader class uses the internal AIR WebKit engine."

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. if you only want to play, try this:
browser.loadURL("https://www.youtube.com/v/hFupHx5G44s");